# Why button doesnt fire javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, button

I have no idea why the  button click function is not firing in Javascript, am I missing something? I tried:

aspx.page

```
<input type="button" id="tglBtn"  onclick="changeName(this) "    runat="server"  />
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="tglBtn" OnClientClick="changeName(this);" runat="server"  />
```

or

```
   <input type="button" id="tglBtn" OnClientClick="changeName(this);return false;" runat="server"  />
```

Javascript

```
function changeName(obj) {
        alert("hey");
        if ($(obj).attr("Value") == "Open") {
            $(obj).val("Close");
        }
        else {
            $(obj).val("Open");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you have included your scripts correctly, the first version you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DyU7k/ Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Did u included jquery files?

Comment: Yes I do have jquery files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it work so fine to me.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="button" id="tglbtn" onclick="changeName(this)" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeName(obj) {

            alert("hey");
            if ($(obj).attr("Value") == "Open") {
                $(obj).val("Close");
            }
            else {
                $(obj).val("Open");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Do you have jQuery? If you dont have just add a jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake... now try this...

```
<asp:Button id="tglBtn"  OnClientClick="return changeName()" runat="server"><asp>
```

Comment: You can put runat="server" on any HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClientClick` is work on asp.net controls (not on html controls that you have apply the run on server).

So the first line is only left.

```
<input type="button" id="tglBtn"  onclick="changeName(this) "    runat="server"  />
```

This line is run, but at the same time you make Post Back, so you probably not have the time to see the results of javascript. Of course you may have some other javascript bugs, if you open your browser console you can see if the javascript runs with out errors.

Answer (score -1):

Use ASP:Button instead.
see below code

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="tglBtn" onclientclick="return changeName()" Text="submit" />
//in head section
<script language="Javascript">
   function changeName()
   {
      alert("I am in function");
      document.getElementById("tglBtn").value = "New name";
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

it will resolve your issue

Comment: -1 because the button is not render the id as you have type it. Second you can pass the `this` and not look again by id. To get the rendered is you type `<%=tglBtn.ClientID%>` on page, or apply static name.

Comment: @Aristos `because the button is not render the id as you have type it` not always it is same if you don't use `Master Page` and `User controls`.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ Ok, and this is good programming ? to left it in random ? Because you totally left it random - you left it on how asp.net decide how to create the id, if asp.net change some subversion and change this as breaking change, go and change all your page... Beside that this is a snipped code that must work no matter if you place it on first page.